# Windows version of ~/Desktop

Tags: windows, shortcuts

in linux `~/Desktop` is a shortcut for `/path/to/my/desktop/` is there a windows equivalent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes in fact.

```
%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

Comment: You may want to put quotes around that in practical usage, as the `%userprofile%` path often has spaces in it (i.e. `C:\documents and settings\ `).

Comment: @nhinkle Only in XP and 2k.

Comment: True, but usernames can have spaces too. It's not critical to the answer, but I thought I'd add the note for people reading this question in the future.